# Tool to calculate Cyclomatic Complexity for C code

Tags: c, cyclomatic-complexity

I want a tool to analyse my code quality and after a bit of googling I think I understand that Cyclomatic Complexity could be something to start with here. I have tried to get several tools working but without success (found out that most are developed for Java). My requirements are:

- Should work on C code
- Should work on Ubuntu (12.04)
- Should be free
- (Optional) Plugin for eclipse

I would be grateful for any help

Comment: Have looked to other questions like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/125898/tool-for-calculating-cyclomatic-complexity)

Comment: I have read that and tried some of them but most are for other languages. But I actually went back there now and found one called [lizard](https://github.com/terryyin/lizard) that actually does what I want but I think it would be better to have a GUI or Eclipse plugin.

Answer (score 3):

There is [Eclipse metriculator plugin](http://marketplace.eclipse.org/content/metriculator).

There is also [cccc](http://sourceforge.net/projects/cccc/) - an open source program to analyze code.

Comment: Isn't Metrics plugin for java?

Comment: @user2021579 works for c and c++

Comment: [This](http://metrics.sourceforge.net/) says "metrics are all about counting aspects of your java code".

Comment: @user2021579 Ok, I actually use metriculator, and that is for c and c++.

Comment: @BЈовић no it's not metriculator is c++ only https://github.com/ideadapt/metriculator/issues/13